# Coredata merges relationship instead of overwriting it

Tags: ios, core-data

I have two coredata entities, say Class and Student with a one to many relationship (Cascade delete, ordered). I have enabled unique constraint on an entity customId. customId is not optional
When I create a new ClassX object with student A and B, it works fine.

The way I update this object (Class) is by creating a new object with same 'customId' which has all the relationships defined. For instance, Now ClassX has student C and D.
When I save the context, it leads to a final object ClassX with students A, B, C and D. 
The expectation here is to have all the relationships overwritten and class X should only have C and D as students.

I have tried different merge policies (NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy and NSOverwriteMergePolicy), but both end up merging the relationship objects instead of overwriting

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Core Data defaults to create one-to-many relationships with the object for the “to-many” side of the relationship of type `NSSet`.

`NSSet` represents a unique collection of objects. [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsset).

When you check the “Ordered” checkbox in the object model editor, instead of `NSSet`, Core Data will provide a “to-many” object of type `NSOrderedSet`. [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsorderedset).

A Set is by nature and as mentioned above, a unique collection. For more information on this there are some good blogs on collections that I’d suggest are worth a read. If I find any links I’ll post them here.

So when you add an object to a “to-many” relationship, the boilerplate code prepared by Xcode and the Core Data framework will add the object into a set.

If you want to “overwrite”... you’ll need to remove the existing objects first and then add the new objects.

Comment: To remove the existing object, I will need to fetch the object from the persistent store, which kinda defeats the purpose of uniquing in coredata.

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same scenarion, the following solution helped me to resolve the relationship by overriding the relationship.

1. i created my own custom NSMergePolicy
2. `override func resolve(constraintConflicts list: [NSConstraintConflict]) throws` - By overriding the resolve method, i could able to give my custom resolving implementation.
3. if any relationship changes happened, i was deleting the store relationship data with `storeObject.linkedContacts?.forEach { storeObject.managedObjectContext?.delete($0) }`. this will help to override our updated data.

```
class CustomMergePolicy: NSMergePolicy {
    
        class func create() -> MergePolicy {
            return MergePolicy(merge: .mergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicyType)
        }
        
        private override init(merge ty: NSMergePolicyType) {
            super.init(merge: ty)
        }
    
        /* 
         NOTE: Things to consider
         1. Even if we edit single property in the json -> all keys coming as changedKeys
         2. if json property become null or empty -> its not coming as changedKeys when resolving conflicts
         */
        override func resolve(constraintConflicts list: [NSConstraintConflict]) throws {
            for conflict in list {
                guard let storeObject = conflict.databaseObject else {
                    try super.resolve(constraintConflicts: list)
                    return
                }
    
                var allKeys = Array(storeObject.entity.attributesByName.keys)
                allKeys.append(contentsOf: storeObject.entity.relationshipsByName.keys)
    
                for conflicting in conflict.conflictingObjects {
                    let changedKeys = conflicting.changedValues().keys
                    let unchangedKeys = allKeys.filter { !changedKeys.contains($0) }
    
                    func takeValueFromStoreForUnchangedKeys() {
                        for key in unchangedKeys {
                            let value = storeObject.value(forKey: key)
                            conflicting.setValue(value, forKey: key)
                        }
                    }
                    switch conflicting {
                    case conflicting as? Item:
                        guard let storeObject = storeObject as? Item else { fallthrough }
                        let hasLinkedContactChanges = changedKeys.contains("linkedContacts")
                        let isLinkedContactNullified = !storeObject.linkedContacts.isNilOrEmpty && !hasLinkedContactChanges // #2
                        let hasChanges = hasLinkedContactChanges || isLinkedContactNullified
                        func deleteStoreLinkedContacts() {
                            storeObject.linkedContacts?.forEach { storeObject.managedObjectContext?.delete($0) }
                        }
                        hasChanges
                        ? deleteStoreLinkedContacts()
                        : takeValueFromStoreForUnchangedKeys() // this never executed - need to find scenario
                    default:
                        takeValueFromStoreForUnchangedKeys()
                    }
                }
            }
    
            try super.resolve(constraintConflicts: list)
        }
    }
```

i have tested with default and updated json. which takes the updated json relationship values by discarding the store relationship data.

Bit delayed answer, hope this help others to solve the issue.